# Day-One executive actions from Biden's predecessors?

Tags: united-states, president, executive-order

Commenting on Biden's plan to sign a number of executive orders on Inauguration Day, the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/biden-trump-orders-masks/2021/01/20/7b6a1bec-5a98-11eb-b8bd-ee36b1cd18bf_story.html) quotes Jen Psaki as follows:

> “President-elect Biden is taking historic action on Day One to advance his agenda — including signing 15 executive actions and asking agencies to take steps in an additional two areas,” incoming White House press secretary Jen Psaki said. “This compares to two Day One executive actions from Biden’s four predecessors in the White House combined.”

I'm interested in the last sentence, the "two Day One executive actions" signed by Biden's four predecessors (Trump, Obama, Bush, Clinton). Apparently, one of them is Executive Order 13765 signed by Trump, which, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13765), sets out "interim procedures in anticipation of repeal of the Affordable Care Act (Obamacare)".

But I couldn't find the second Day-One executive action that Psaki refers to. Which president signed it, and what was its content?

Comment: It's interesting to note that a lot of the time presidential candidates _say_ they'll do something on Day One.  I'm not surprised that a lot of it doesn't actually happen, but I _am_ surprised that it's as rare as it is. Good to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other Day-One executive action was [Executive Order 12834](https://www.archives.gov/files/federal-register/executive-orders/pdf/12834.pdf) - Ethics Commitments by Executive Branch Appointees, which was signed on 20th Jan 1993 by President Bill Clinton. It set out a pledge that Clinton's Executive Branch appointments were required to make, as well as provisions for its administration and enforcement. This order was later revoked by Clinton in December 2000, just before he left office.

Similiar executive orders defining such pledges were also signed by President Obama ([EO 13490](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/the-press-office/ethics-commitments-executive-branch-personnel)) and President Trump ([EO 13770](https://www2.oge.gov/web/oge.nsf/0/A43C4DBAB9EC4DC7852580BC006FBA83/$FILE/Exec%20Order%2013770.pdf)), although neither was signed on either president's first day in office.